# Geometry nodes: How to reduce point density on straight sections of a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

I saw this example where the straight sections of a curve are represented by just 1 face, while curved sections have more subdivisions. How can I achieve this effect in Blender 3.4?

https://twitter.com/i/status/1469408940681310212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This group will return the unsigned edge-angle, on each point of an (evaluated) curve:

[image]

..By, for each point **B** of **ABC**,  taking the dot-product of **BA** and **BC**. On acyclic curves, it preserves end-points.

It can be used like this to dissolve control-points at edges which  meet at less than a threshold angle, given in degrees:

[image]

[image] (Blender 3.41 stable)

[image]

Comment: Nice one! btw: This example includes a solution for Blender versions below 3.4: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288704/

Comment: @quellenform Hi, q!   Ooops.. look like I've answered a dupe, again, strictly..

Comment: Thanks - this works quite well!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by compare normals with neighboring point like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank! it works pretty well.

But I have an issue with a specific shape. It's a sort of polygon with many angles. Kind of like the Z-shaped tetris block but with random angles. Not always 90°.

In some corners I get 2-3 edges instead of only 1 edge. And on one face I still have one edge that I can't get rid of somehow.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is working quite well but in some corners I have 2-3 edges still instead of only 1. And on this one side here I have one edge which I can't get rid of. I assume it's the starting position?