# Fill holes in a convex mesh using Geometry Nodes

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I need to fill the holes in the mesh using Geometry Nodes:

[image]

I've tried using the *Convex Hull* node, but it creates a lot of extra edges:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

[image]

<sub>(Blender 3.6.1)</sub>

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can easily create this star-shape Icosahedron class 2 type of mesh using [Geodesic Domes addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/geodesic_domes.html)  using [these settings](https://snipboard.io/YVmqrZ.jpg)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you, but i have a strong "Addon-phobia" :) Plus, I want to use transform animation, so it's important that this is achieved by geometry nodes

Comment: It's an included addon. Many of blender's current functions were, at one point, addons. But ok, do you.

Comment: You could decimate the triangulated faces that `Convex Hull` creates for you with this technique: ["Decimate: Planar" in Geo nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299231/decimate-planar-in-geo-nodes). Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPQgi.jpg

Comment: @quellenform Only "native" nodes are used, so this answer works for me. Write this as a complete answer to close the question.

Comment: If the other answer basically is a solution to your question, I would rather say this question could be closed as a duplicate with a link to the other question...?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i was thinking the same thing, but this is about how to fill faces. Maybe someone can come up with a solution on how to fill faces? Convex Hull doesn't work properly.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Technically, you're absolutely right, which is why I was still hesitant. The question is different, but the solution is the same in this particular case. I'll leave the question open for now, because there may be another solution.

Comment: I solved your dilemma by editing the title to more accurately describe the OP's problem - cheers! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach that puts missing pentagons in your holes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this question deserves this answer (maybe it should be marked as duplicate), but I'll post it anyway. Maybe another idea will come up that will solve the task better.

My idea would be to proceed exactly as in the question, and remove the excess edges that `Convex Hull` creates with another node group, which is described in more detail here: ["Decimate: Planar" in Geo nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299231/decimate-planar-in-geo-nodes)

[image: Remove excess edges]

In this example, the node "299231" contains exactly the node group given in the other answer.

It may not be the best solution, but it works.