# Dissolve collinear points - Geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, topology

I am looking for a way to remove collinear (in a straight line, I think?) points from a flat N-gon face, with geometry nodes. I can select the desired points with the edge angle node, but I am not sure how to fill the gap left by deleting them. Is there a way to fill the gaps left by deleting, or is there another way, to "dissolve" the points.

Below is an example mesh (extruded to show the points/edges to be removed).

[image: Example mesh - Extruded to show the points/edges to be removed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299231/

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks very much.