# Geometry Nodes: Delete edges based on edge angle

Tags: geometry-nodes

There were some questions like this but none of them helped me with this.

So, how to delete edges based on edge angle (or use boolean math to delete the flat edges)?

The red overpainted edges of the mesh in the image below should get deleted. Each of the edges has 2 vertices of the same height in them.

(The mesh that visualizes the height of the edges is just for clarification purposes.)

[image]

Comment: the problem with your provided image is, that we have no idea whether this is all flat (z=0) or has height ...or whatever

Comment: This answer might be helpful (part of the node tree deletes points along a straight line): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288704 ...or have I misunderstood you? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Chris I made the image and explanation more clear

Comment: @quellenform Hmm, I have hard time of applying the answer to this question. I made the question more clear, I hope it helps some more. The flat edges should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do what I needed!

[image]

Thanks to [Chanfiroly](https://x.com/chanfiroly/status/1726986710515580962?s=20) on X